# Can MongoDB Fill In Blank Documents

Tags: mongodb

Currently I have a collection of daily records like this:

```
[{
    date: 2017-03-01 (isoDate),
    numItems: 12
},{
    date: 2017-03-04 (isoDate),
    numItems: 2
},{
    date: 2017-03-05 (isoDate),
    numItems: 4
},{
    date: 2017-03-07 (isoDate),
    numItems: 5
}]
```

Is there a way in mongo to aggregate the records so that it will fill in the missing days and zero out the `numItems`, to return this:

```
[{
    date: 2017-03-01 (isoDate),
    numItems: 12
},{
    date: 2017-03-02 (isoDate),
    numItems: 0
},{
    date: 2017-03-03 (isoDate),
    numItems: 0
},{
    date: 2017-03-04 (isoDate),
    numItems: 2
},{
    date: 2017-03-05 (isoDate),
    numItems: 4
},{
    date: 2017-03-06 (isoDate),
    numItems: 0
},{
    date: 2017-03-07 (isoDate),
    numItems: 5
}]
```

Or, is it best to do this as post processing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fill missing dates in records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52235027/fill-missing-dates-in-records)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this within the database if you use a [Calendar Collection](http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables) i.e. a helper collection which is *just a list of dates*, without gaps. Using such a calendar collection, you could put together an aggregation which:

1. Uses the [$lookup operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to join the calendar collection to your collection of daily records
2. Reshapes the data (using [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) as necessary) to convert the joined data (an array of subdocuments) into the desired structure
3. Uses the [ifnull operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) in a [$project stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to make sure the numItems field is given a default value of 0 in the documents where it does not already exist

Comment: Not my idea - I can't remember where I first read about them but I've been happily proselytising the idea of calendar tables and number tables, handy for ad hoc database reporting, for years and years now.

Comment: There is an example of this technique at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48274099/174843; but instead of using a standalone calendar collection, the list of dates is generated using the [$range operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/).