# MongoDB fill-in data that is not included in the query result

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Let's say I have a collection that contains this data:

```
{"date" : ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 3 }
{"date" : ISODate("2018-01-04T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 5 }
```

What mongodb functions should I use so that I can generate a query that will result to this:

```
{"date" : ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 3 }
{"date" : ISODate("2018-01-02T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 0 }
{"date" : ISODate("2018-01-03T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 0 }
{"date" : ISODate("2018-01-04T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 5 }
{"date" : ISODate("2018-01-05T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 0 }
```

Basically, I want to iterate a date range and if that given date is not in the collection, I will just output a 'count':0 for it.

I can probably do this by just retrieving the documents and have a javascript code that will fill in the data that's not in the results but I would just like to know if it's possible by only using mongodb query.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's possible without retrieving the data. And even if you do, you would have to solve multi-threading problems. But if it works for you, you can check for empty dates when you actually retrieve the data to use for your purpose. So say if you need to retrieve 5th and the date right b4 and if 3 days are missing, then you know 3 days are missing.

Comment: Do it on your end, don't do extra computations than needed at DB end

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can MongoDB Fill In Blank Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961228/can-mongodb-fill-in-blank-documents)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its possible through `$range` to generate a range and do self look up

steps

1. `$group` - find min and max date dynamically, hard-code if required
2. `$project` - generate `$range`, based on min & max, hard-code if required
3. `$unwind` - unwind range to document
4. `$project` - generate date by generated number
5. `$lookup` - self join with collection based on date
6. `$project` - if match found return count, else then 0. change `$ifNull` to `$cond` if mongo version is less than 3.6

aggregate pipeline

```
db.t.aggregate(
    [   
        {
            $group : { _id : null, startDate : { "$min" : "$date" }, endDate : { "$max" : "$date" }} 
        },
        {
            $project : { _id : 0 , startDate : 1,  genNo : { $range : [ { $add : [ {"$dayOfMonth" : "$startDate"}, -1 ] }, { $add : [ {"$dayOfMonth" : "$endDate"} , 1 ] } ] } }
        },
        {
            $unwind : "$genNo"
        },
        {
            $project : { genDate : { $add : [ "$startDate", { $multiply : [ "$genNo" , 86400000 ] } ] } }
        },
        {
            $lookup : {
                from : "t",
                localField : "genDate",
                foreignField : "date",
                as : "out"
            }
        },
        {
            $project : { date : "$genDate", count : { $ifNull : [ { $arrayElemAt : ["$out.count", 0 ] }, 0 ] } }
        }
    ]
)
```

collection

```
> db.t.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5d78d5423b9839ce07bd77"), "date" : ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5d78d5423b9839ce07bd78"), "date" : ISODate("2018-01-04T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 5 }
>
```

aggregation result

```
{ "date" : ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 3 }
{ "date" : ISODate("2018-01-02T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 0 }
{ "date" : ISODate("2018-01-03T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 0 }
{ "date" : ISODate("2018-01-04T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 5 }
{ "date" : ISODate("2018-01-05T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 0 }
>
```