# Mongo query to return count 0 in non existing dates in group by date query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to display 0 if there is no document with a given range of date. I wrote a mongo query as below.

```
{$match:convQuery},
{$group:{
    _id:{year:{$year:"$created_at"},month:{$month:"$created_at"},day:{$dayOfMonth:"$created_at"}},
        count:{$sum:1}
}},
{$sort:{"_id.year":1,"_id.month":1,"_id.day":1}}
```

The out put of above query is giving the data for existing documents in the given start and end time provided in convQuery. I have given the start and end time from feb 15 to feb 25. for that i got the below output.

```
{ _id: { year: 2019, month: 2, day: 18 }, count: 30 }
{ _id: { year: 2019, month: 2, day: 19 }, count: 81 }
{ _id: { year: 2019, month: 2, day: 20 }, count: 75 }
{ _id: { year: 2019, month: 2, day: 21 }, count: 90 }
{ _id: { year: 2019, month: 2, day: 22 }, count: 83 }
{ _id: { year: 2019, month: 2, day: 23 }, count: 37 }
```

But what i need is , to get the count as 0 for the rest of the dates.

is there any way to get that output. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This can be done using e.g. `$range` but it's a little nasty and most of the time pointless. Why don't you handle this on the client side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB Aggregation - Output Non-existent Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52235027/mongodb-aggregation-output-non-existent-dates)

Comment: @dnickless, my case is to handle this at backend

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I need to get exact count, not 1. there i am getting 1 if document exist. How can i get the existed count?

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate answers. It is same as your needs