# How Do I aggregate mongoDB query which retrieves data monthly between two Dates?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following collection,

```
Todos = {
username:{ type: String},
type: {type: String}     // can be A | B
todos: [
 title: {type: String},
 createdAt: {type: String} 
]
}
```

Suppose I have inputs `fromDate = "1-3-2019", toDate = "1-5-2019" and type = "A"`
this should result in the count of todos of all the users with type: "A" of months 3 and 4 individually.

I have tried this.

```
const result = await Todos.aggregate([
        {
          $match: { type: 'A' }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            todos: {
              $filter: {
                input: '$todos',
                as: 'todo',
                cond: {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      $gte: [
                        { $toDate: '$$todo.createdAt' },
                        { $toDate: fromDate }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $lte: [
                        { $toDate: '$$todo.createdAt' },
                        { $toDate: toDate }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        { $group: { _id: '', count: { $sum: { $size: '$todos' } } } },
        { $project: { totalTodos: '$count' } }
      ])
```

But this is an inappropriate result what I want instead of the result with 2 counts, the first count will give the todos of March, and the second will gives all todos of April since there are two months between this input dates.

Any help would be appreciated Thank you.

Comment: Please post the data you used to run the query. The query looks fine. If you use `todos` array with data in two documents, for example: `[ { title: "t1", createdAt: "1-3-2019" }, {title: "t2", createdAt: "12-8-2019"} ]` and `[ { title: "t21", createdAt: "1-5-2019" }, {title: "t22", createdAt: "1-4-2019"} ]`, the query counts `3`.

Comment: @prasad_ I just need monthwise count.Let's assume above inputs if `fromDate = "1-4-2019"` and `toDate = "12-8-2019" ` then it should results in 4 counts since there are 4 months in between the input dates.

Comment: So the result would be,
`{ firstMonthCount = 1,
secondMonthCount = 1,
thirdMonthCount = 0,
fourthMonthCount = 1 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your query to add steps to count by months of `createdAt` field. Note that all date fields in this post are assumed as in the format `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Some sample documents:

```
{ type: "A", todo: [ { title: "t1", createdAt: "1-3-2019" }, {title: "t2", createdAt: "12-8-2019"} ] },
{ type: "A", todo: [ { title: "t21", createdAt: "30-5-2019" }, {title: "t22", createdAt: "1-4-2019"} ] }, 
{ type: "A", todo: [ { title: "t90", createdAt: "26-3-2019" }, {title: "t92", createdAt: "19-9-2018"}, {title: "t99", createdAt: "1-5-2019"}  ] }
```

*The query:*

```
var FROM_DATE = "1-3-2019"
var TO_DATE = "31-5-2019"

db.todos.aggregate( [
  {
    $match: { type: 'A' }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      todo: {
        $filter: {
          input: '$todo',
          as: 'todo',
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $gte: [
                  { $toDate: '$$todo.createdAt' },
                  { $toDate: FROM_DATE }
                ]
              },
              {
                $lte: [
                  { $toDate: '$$todo.createdAt' },
                  { $toDate: TO_DATE }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$todo" },
  { $project: { createdAtMonth: { $month: { $toDate: "$todo.createdAt"  } } } },
  { $group: { _id: "$createdAtMonth", countByMonth: { $sum: 1 } } },
  { $project: { createdAtMonth: "$_id", countByMonth: 1, _id: 0 } },
] )
```

*The Output:*

```
{ "countByMonth" : 1, "createdAtMonth" : 4 }
{ "countByMonth" : 2, "createdAtMonth" : 5 }
{ "countByMonth" : 2, "createdAtMonth" : 3 }
```

Comment: thank you @prasad_ this is the exact solution that I was looking for.

Comment: Hey @prasad_ could you please tell me that how can I sets missing fields.
In the above scenario if month 4 has count 0 then mongodb removes that month field from the result.
So how can I set that count to 0.

Comment: If month 4 has no data how can you count? I am not sure if its possible. The grouping is done by available data only.

Comment: May be take a look at this post for some ideas: [fill-missing-dates-in-records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52235027/fill-missing-dates-in-records).

Comment: I got the idea Thank you.