# Aggregate by all days of month mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

Hey i need to get the sum of all totalPrice group by days

I get this result

[image]

but i need to fetch all rest days of month even if it returns 0

i need solution 
this is my code

```
Order.aggregate([
    { $project: { yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: '$created' }}, totalPrice:"$totalPrice" }},
    { $group: { _id: "$yearMonthDay", count: { $sum: 1 }, total: {"$sum": "$totalPrice"} }},
    { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
    { $group: { _id: null, stats: { $push: "$$ROOT" }}}, 
    {
        $project: {
             results: {
                $map: {
                    input:{ $range:[16,31] },
                    as: 'day',
                    in: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: {
                                dateIndex: {
                                    "$indexOfArray": ["$stats._id", {$dateToString:{ date:{$dateFromParts:{'year':2020, 'month':5, 'day':"$$day"}}, format:'%Y-%m-%d'}}]
                                }
                            },
                            in: {
                                $cond: {
                                    if: { $ne: ["$$dateIndex", -1] },
                                    then: { $arrayElemAt: ["$stats", "$$dateIndex"] },
                                    else: { _id: {$dateToString:{ date:{$dateFromParts:{'year':2020, 'month':5, 'day':"$$day"}}, format:'%Y-%m-%d'}, count: 0, total: 0 } }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    { $unwind: "$results" },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$results"}}
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fill missing dates in records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52235027/fill-missing-dates-in-records)

Comment: I did not understand anything, I think this is not the same
i have the totalprice variable 
i need just all days even total is 0

Comment: Can you post please expected result? What it should return (`2020-05-16`, `2020-05-15`, `2020-05-14`, `2020-05-13`, ...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should work for you.

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
{ $project: { yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: '$created' }}, totalPrice:"$totalPrice" }},
{ $group: { _id: "$yearMonthDay", count: { $sum: 1 }, total: {"$sum": "$totalPrice"} }},
{ $sort: { _id: -1 } },
{ $group: { _id: null, stats: { $push: "$$ROOT" }}, 
{
    $project: {
        results: {
            $map: {
                input: ["2020-05-16","2020-05-15","2020-05-14","2020-05-13","2020-05-12"],
                as: "date",
                in: {
                    $let: {
                        vars: {
                            dateIndex: {
                                "$indexOfArray": ["$stats._id", "$$date"]
                            }
                        },
                        in: {
                            $cond: {
                                if: { $ne: ["$$dateIndex", -1] },
                                then: { $arrayElemAt: ["$stats", "$$dateIndex"] },
                                else: { _id: "$$date", count: 0, total: 0 }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, 
{ $unwind: "$results" },
{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$results"}}
])
```

The First 3 steps is same as yours.

`{ $group: { _id: null, stats: { $push: "$$ROOT" }}` will push previous stage results into an arrray `stats` which we will use for lookup in later stage.

In last stage, we will create possible date range and iterate over that.
for each key in range.

`"$indexOfArray": ["$stats._id", "$$date"]` will check if date is present in `stats` array or not

Then we will use that index to fetch value from `stats` array otherwise push default values.

As these results are still under `results`, we will `unwind` that array and move to `root`.

**If you server version is above 3.6**, 
we can simplify date range creation part as well. let's initialize input arrays as days using `$range`.

```
input:{ $range:[16,31] },
as: 'day'
```

and modifiy `dateIndex` part like this

```
dateIndex: {
   "$indexOfArray": ["$stats._id", {$dateToString:{ date:{$dateFromParts:{'year':2020, 'month':5, 'day':"$$day"}}, format:'%Y-%m-%d'}]
}
```

And change default value part as well similarly.

```
else: { _id: {$dateToString:{ date:{$dateFromParts:{'year':2020, 'month':5, 'day':"$$day"}}, format:'%Y-%m-%d'}}, count: 0, total: 0 }
```

Or **alternatively**, we can also use `concat` for generating keys

```
dateIndex: {
   "$indexOfArray": ["$stats._id", {$concat:["2020-05","-", {$convert:{input:"$$day", to:"string"}}]}]
}
```

// And default value

```
else: { _id: {$concat:["2020-05","-", {$convert:{input:"$$day", to:"string"}}]}, count: 0, total: 0 }
```

Similarly, you can run another loop for months as well.

Comment: Thank you but i have issue when i change to date range "errmsg": "Use of undefined variable: date",

Comment: @AdelStiti if date range within the same month, `$range` approach would be helpful.

Comment: i have this error "errmsg": "Use of undefined variable: date", "code": 17276,

Comment: @AdelStiti that's because `else: { _id: "$$date", count: 0, total: 0 }` variable in here should `$$day` as you using `day` as variable. I have updated in answer too. :)

Comment: Thank you its work for `concat ` but return problem with the first solution "errmsg": "An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $dateToString: { date: { $dateFromParts: { year: 2020, month: 5, day: \"$$day\" } }, format: \"%Y-%m-%d\" }, count: 0, total: 0 }   i edited the latest query

Comment: @AdelStiti there was inbalance in braces. fixed.

Comment: that will depend upon what you provide in range. `$range:[16,31]`. these inputs you need to control from client-side.